# ExtJS hierarchical select - Category selector with tree like data structure with multiple select fields

Tags: ajax, extjs, drop-down-menu, tree, html-select

I have a category selector with up to 4 level depth. The selectable values are stored in one table. This Table has the values: id, parentId, level and a label. This builds a hierarchical structure.

- 1 Root Category
- -- 2. Sub Category
- ---- 3. Sub Sub Category
- ------ 4. Sub sub sub Category

Now I want to have 4 select fields. Only the first is activated the others are hidden and deactivated. If this one is selected, the second gets filtered/updated by the first and activated. ... and so on. I only want to return the id of the deepest category as my selected category. However some categories only have 2 or 3 levels. If the form loads it should refill itself backwards from the selected field by knowing its level and getting its parents.

Does such a selector already exist? Do you have examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since couple of people already asked whether I solved the problem. Yes, I'm using xtemplate and only have one selector showing the structure.

Comment: No, i only have one dropdown field and style this with senchas xtemplate. Deeper categories are intended more. Since I have only about 80 categories this is reasonable for the users. Most users use the dropdown the first time and then use the type a head functionality.